# Directional vs Non-Directional Alternative Hypothesis in Bayesian Model Comparison?

Tags: bayesian, bayes-factors

I have recently completed a study where I hypothesised a significant difference between two groups. I hypothesised that Group B would be report a significantly lower score on the outcome variable on average following the experimental manipulation than group A.

The t-test testing this hypothesis was non-significant (*p* = .998).

There was so little difference in the scores that I thought I might perform a post-hoc test for equivalence using a Bayes Factor to test the hypothesis of no difference against the alternative hypothesis of some difference.

My question is should the alternative hypothesis I test the null hypothesis against be directional like my original hypothesis, or should it be bi-directional, testing the null hypothesis of no difference against the alternative of *any difference* (i.e. a difference in *any* direction, not just the original direction I hypothesised)?